# Do all recursion based algorithms can be converted into iterative (loop based) algorithms?

Tags: loops, recursion

As in case of finding factorial of a number or fibonacci series, we can write both recursion based and loop based solutions. Is recursion always convertible to loop based solution. If not, please give example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert any recursive algorithm to an iterative one by explicitly storing the stack in your own object and maintaining it between iterations.